# Error reading JSON file containing square brackets in Python

Tags: python, json, square-bracket

I need to modify the values of a JSON file that is being used by another program. It looks like this:

```
[
  {
  "ENABLED": "True",
  "NAME": "Cage",
  "CODE": "3928273",
  "COLOR": "Green"
  }
]
```

This causes my script (below) to throw errors. It works perfectly if I delete the square brackets from the original JSON file. But the issue with that is the program that uses it requires the square brackets to be there.

I need to write the modified values back to the file, and the JSON file must contain the square brackets after I'm done writing to it. My current non-functioning code is:

```
import json

with open('myfile.json', 'r+') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
    json_data['NAME'] = "Nick"
    f.seek(0)
    json.dump(json_data, f, indent=4)
    f.truncate()
```

The error I get is *"json_data['SYMBOL'] = "Nick"
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"* Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you have to try ```json_data[0]['NAME'] = "Nick"``` at line 4

Comment: Your dictionary is inside of the one-element list.

Comment: As general advice: once you've called `json.load`, the thing that you have is *just an ordinary Python value*, that you work with *exactly* as if you had gotten that data in *any other way* besides loading it from JSON. The square brackets denote a JSON array, which turns into a Python list. If you weren't already expecting that, then it may be that you really need to understand the JSON format itself better. (BTW: the `square` tag is for something unrelated. When you add tags to your post, please read the descriptions that pop up.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using square brackets, you need to access the dictionary inside to modify the `NAME` variable. Just needed to add `[0]` in between `json_data` and `['NAME']` in the modification. This will access the first element of the list, which is the dictionary.

```
import json

with open('myfile.json', 'r+') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
    json_data[0]['NAME'] = "Nick"
    f.seek(0)
    json.dump(json_data, f, indent=4)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Been struggling for a long time trying to figure this out

Comment: @jedi2191 Glad to help! If you want, you can upvote and accept this answer.